# How can I grant ownership of a mutex to a specific thread?

Tags: multithreading, mutex, critical-section

Imagine I have a mutex locked. There is unlimited number of other threads waiting to lock the mutex. When I unlock the mutex, one of those threads will be chosen to enter the critical section. However I have no control over which one. What if I want specific thread to enter the critical section?

I am prety sure this cannot be done  using POSIX mutex, however, can I emulate the behaviour using different synchronisation object(s)?

Comment: The only guarantee you'll get is fairness in some mechanisms, but none of them have the features you require. Can't you redesign your algorithm to not depend on which thread goes through first? Perhaps if you explain what you're doing we can think of something.

Comment: It's abot preventing a deadlock: I am in a critical section and I am about to lock a different critical section. However, I know there's another thread that has the latter CS locked and is attempting to lock the former CS. To prevent the deadlock, I need to notify the other thread that is should cancel its attempt to lock the former CS.

Comment: Can't each thread acquire all the locks in the same order? Then you won't have deadlock issues.

Comment: No, it can't. Btw, see a viable -- although not very efficient -- solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a mutex, a condition variable and a thread id to achive that.

Before unlocking the mutex the thread sets the target thread id, broadcasts the condition variable and releases the mutex. The waiting threads wake up, lock the mutex and check whether the target thread id equals to this thread id. If not the thread goes back to wait.

An optimization to this method to avoid waking up all waiting threads just to check the target thread id and then go back to wait would be to use a separate condition variable for each waiting thread. This way the signaling thread would notify the condition variable of the particular target thread.

---

Another option is to use signals sent to a particular thread. Let's say we use `SIGRTMIN`for this purpose. First, all threads block this signal at the start, so that the signal becomes pending and doesn't get lost when the thread isn't waiting for it. When a thread wants to lock the mutex it first calls `sigwait()` which atomically unblocks `SIGRTMIN` and waits for it or delivers an already pending one. Once the thread received the signal it can proceed and lock the mutex. The signaling thread uses `pthread_kill(target_thread_id, SIGRTMIN)` to wake up a particular thread.

Comment: Yep. I've done it that way. I was concerned about the performance overhead of randomly letting threads into the critical section and checking whether it's the right thread. At the moment I cannot think of anything better though.

Comment: @MartinSustrik I added an alternative method.